# Get delete id in controller to delete mysql record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have this in AuthController:

```php
public function DelFunc() {

    if(Auth::check() === true) {
        $deleted = DB::delete('delete from funcionarios where id = ?',[$id]);
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin.login');
}
```

But I get this error: Undefined variable: id

I have this button in my view:

```html
<a href="../admin/delFunc?id={{$empresa->id}}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
</a>
```

I know my question is simple, but, how can I get the id value on AuthController to delete this record?

I also have this route:

```php
Route::get('/admin/delFunc', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'delFunc'])->name('delFunc');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bunch of red flags here:

- Why is this going into a controller called `AuthController` when it is working with a `Funcionario` object?
- Why direct database queries instead of using Eloquent models?
- You should not be deleting items by GET method, this is very dangerous.
- Authentication is to be done by middleware, not by checking within every controller method.
- And last, your method should also have a more conventional name like `destroy`.

Route parameters are defined in the route definition with braces like "/admin/delete/{func}" and then bound to objects in the controller method definition.

So, putting all that together, what it should look like is:

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\FuncionarioController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware("auth")->group(function ($router) {
    $router->delete('/funcionario/{func}', [FuncionarioController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->name('funcionario.destroy');
});
```

And then in your controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Funcionario;

class FuncionarioController extends Controller {

    public function destroy(Funcionario $func)
    {
        $func->delete();
        return redirect()
            ->route('admin.login')
            ->with('success', __('Funcionario deleted'));
    }
}
```

And your view would look like this, assuming your value is passed in the `$id` variable:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route("funcionario.destroy", $id) }}">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit">{{ __("Delete") }}</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No problem, hope it all makes sense!

Comment: Method name `destroy` is more appropriate and the route name `functionario.destroy` according to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Comment: Your answer was just perfect, so I thought i would add that bit too :)

Comment: So the first function with `Route::middleware` I put in web.php, is it right? In the second I get this error: unexpected 'destroy' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE). And to delete from mysql what should I use? Thanks again, sorry for my 
lack of knowledge.

Comment: Yes, routes go in web.php. I would hope simple typos in my code should be easy enough to fix. You don't use SQL, that's half the point of Laravel. You just delete the Eloquent instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[$id]` use `[request('id')]`

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but it's a very simplistic approach that doesn't begin to fix all the other issues with the code.